# R - test if a string vector contains any element of another list

Tags: r, string, data.table, grepl, contain

I have:

```
> lst_A <- c("TET","RNR")
> DT_result <- data.table(lst_B = c("RNR_B","BC_TET"))
```

I want:

```
> DT_result <- data.table(lst_B = c("RNR_B","BC_TET"), result = c(TRUE,TRUE))
> DT_result
    lst_B result
1:  RNR_B   TRUE
2: BC_TET   TRUE
```

Basically, for each element in 'lst_B' if it contains any element in 'lst_A' then TRUE otherwise FALSE.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get this using `grepl`.

```
lst_A <- c("TET","RNR")
lst_B = c("RNR_B","BC_TET")

Pattern = paste(lst_A, collapse="|")
grepl(Pattern, lst_B)

library(data.table)
DT_result <- data.table(lst_B, result=grepl(Pattern, lst_B))
DT_result
    lst_B result
1:  RNR_B   TRUE
2: BC_TET   TRUE
```

### Addition

To respond to a comment,  here is an example with more strings to test. Some pass the test,  others not.

```
lst_A <- c("TET","RNR")
lst_B = c("RNR_B","BC_TET", "Fred", "RNR_A", "Zero", "ABC_TET")

Pattern = paste(lst_A, collapse="|")

DT_result <- data.table(lst_B, result=grepl(Pattern, lst_B))
DT_result
     lst_B result
1:   RNR_B   TRUE
2:  BC_TET   TRUE
3:    Fred  FALSE
4:   RNR_A   TRUE
5:    Zero  FALSE
6: ABC_TET   TRUE
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `stringr`'s `str_detect`

```
stringr::str_detect(DT_result$lst_B,'TET|RNR')
[1] TRUE TRUE

#DF['hit']=stringr::str_detect(DT_result$lst_B,'TET|RNR')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    DT_result[,results:=sapply(lst_A,function(x)any(grepl(x,lst_B)))][]
    lst_B results
1:  RNR_B    TRUE
2: BC_TET    TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over each option with `grepl` and then combine with an `|` ('OR'):

```
DT_result[, hit := Reduce(`|`, Map(grepl, lst_A, .(lst_B)))]
DT_result

#    lst_B  hit
#1:  RNR_B TRUE
#2: BC_TET TRUE
```